# Windows Batch Files: if else

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm doing a simple batch file that requires one argument (you can provide more, but I ignore them).

For testing, this is what I have so far.

```
if not %1 == "" (
    dir /s/b %1
) else (
    echo no
)
```

Basically, I want to say if an argument is provided, recursively display all the files in the folder.  Otherwise, say no.

It works when I provide an argument, but if I don't provide one it'll just tell me `( was unexpected at this time`.

I mean, it works, but I wanted to at least display a user-friendly message explaining why it doesn't work. How should I change the code?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
if not %1 == "" (
```

must be

```
if not "%1" == "" (
```

If an argument isn't given, it's completely empty, not even `""` (which represents an empty string in most programming languages). So we use the surrounding quotes to detect an empty argument.

Comment: So it's basically a null value. I get it.

Comment: if not {%1} == {} is safer as "%1"=="" would be true if the value for %1 was quotes.

Comment: @workabyte: Using curly braces as you suggest could be more confusing when `%1` refers to a path or file, because unlike the brace characters `{` and `}`, double-quotes `"` can never appear in any Windows path or filename. So you'd potentially avoid trying to puzzle out things that resolve to `{}} }} == {}`. Perhaps more realistically, note that `{{ea14c59a-889c-495b-8bb6-be78cf960e93}.txt} == {{ea14c59a-889c-495b-8bb6-be78cf960e93.txt}}`, for example, is false.

Answer (score 21):

Surround your `%1` with something.

Eg:

```
if not "%1" == ""
```

Another one I've seen fairly often:

```
if not {%1} == {}
```

And so on...

The problem, as you can likely guess, is that the `%1` is literally replaced with emptiness. It is not 'an empty string' it is actually a blank spot in your source file at that point.

Then after the replacement, the interpreter tries to parse the `if` statement and gets confused.

Answer (score 16):

You have to do the following:

```
if "%1" == "" (
    echo The variable is empty
) ELSE (
    echo The variable contains %1
)
```

Comment: The important part here is that the ELSE should be on the same line as the closing parentheses for the IF statement otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 9):

Another related tip is to use "%~1" instead of "%1".  Type "CALL /?" at the command line in Windows to get more details.

Comment: `%~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")` so no one else has to look it up.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to set a variable, and check whether it is defined:

```
SET ARG=%1
IF DEFINED ARG (echo "It is defined: %1") ELSE (echo "%%1 is not defined")
```

Unfortunately, using `%1` directly with `DEFINED` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this...

if not "A%1" == "A"

if the input argument %1 is null, 
your code will have problem.