# Conditional run for svn revisions in Jenkins

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, jenkins

Previously, I had my jenkins configured to run the latest svn revision only. However, I have to make it conditional now, like when I run the project, I should get an option to choose the svn_revision number I want the project to run on, and if I dont choose svn revision, then it should run on the latest.

I added a string paramter and tried to parameterized the project.

```
Configuration -> Add a parameter -> choose string parameter -> Name it as SVN_REVISION and some default value

Now in Execute windows batch command section:

Declare the svn revision parameter as:

REM Set SVN revison
SVN_REVISION = @${SVN_REVISION}
```

But I still want to have the ability that if I dont choose any value for this parameter, it should run on the latest revision. But I dont know if we could add conditional loops in jenkins batch command section. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your windows batch file

```
if "%SVN_REVISION%" == "" (
    set SVN_REVISION= "HEAD"
)
```

adapted from here [Windows Batch Files: if else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683583/windows-batch-files-if-else)