# Usage of '#' (pound sign) in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've come across a batch file (`portableshell.bat` from the portable version of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html)) that uses `#` and I can't understand why. I've searched online but there seems to be no reference to this usage. I need to imitate the batch file's functionality but I'm wary to do so without understanding what it does exactly.

What's the purpose of `#` here:

```
set drive=%~dp0
set drivep=%drive%
if #%drive:~-1%# == #\# set drivep=%drive:~0,-1%
```

and here:

```
if not #%1# == ## "%drivep%\perl\bin\perl.exe" %* & goto END
```

(here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f0eBYCkm) of the entire file, for reference)

Comment: For whitespace handling in the comparison and properly handling empty values.

Comment: @CodeCaster So it doesn't do anything other than impersonate a character? Am I understanding it correctly if I said that `#` has no function except being a non-functional character that isn't whitespace?

Comment: Yes. You can't compare a value to, say, `null`, because that doesn't work in batch files. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683583/windows-batch-files-if-else. You can use almost any character you like, so `if not [%1] == []` works as well.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see, that clarifies it (and explains why I couldn't find anything on it). If you want to turn this into an actual answer I'll accept it - if you can't be bothered though I'll just answer it myself and include the link. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Feel free to self-answer, no time.

Comment: @CodeCaster, the `#` is merely used to handle empty values, but it does _not_ fix white-space handling; for example, `if # #==##` will fail because of the _space_; to truly fix white-space handling, you need to use `""` like this: `if " "==""`...

Comment: @asc alright, I should type nonsense from memory, thanks.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would explain what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#` character is there so that null/undefined values are properly handled in the comparison, namely to avoid comparing to undefined values should the variable evaluate to them.

This purpose can be served by almost any character (as long as it doesn't have another meaning in this context). Common choices are `[]` and `{}`. `""` can also be used.

> *According to dbenham in the comments, using anything other than `""` is generally bad practice. Quotes can fail when the variable has its own quotes, but is safe when the expanded variable cannot have them, as when expanding paths. The only way that's safe in all cases is [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).*
>
> *Also, there is no reason to surround a variable expansion with `#` or `[` or whatever is used. In the case of the batch file of the question, it is apparently just for symmetry.*

A bit more about this can be read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683583/windows-batch-files-if-else).

*Thanks to [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/) for the help*

Comment: I strongly recommend to use `""` in order to "hide" special characters: for instance, `if #&#==##` will fail because of the `&` (command concatenation character), but `if "&"==""` will work, because the `&` is enclosed within `""` and will therefor be treated literally...

Comment: @aschipfl Noted, but I was just trying to understand _what_ this is. I don't think `#` is a good idea either, since it makes it confusing. On the other hand, there may be cases where `"` is confusing. It's up to the coder to decide what to use I guess.

Comment: There are no similar problematic values. It only protects against undefined values. (and only one `#` is needed for that, the second one serves no purpose). Double quotes are a much better way to go.

Comment: @dbenham corrected. On your second point, it seems strange that a project so widely used by developers would have something purposeless in it - is there no possible reason the batch file is written this way? Perhaps to make it clearer? `#` is missing from [this list](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) of escape characters for instance. Perhaps whoever wrote the batch file thought it best to avoid characters with existing meaning and surrounding the variables in `#` instead of using just one was also for clarity.

Comment: Using anything other than quotes is generally a bad practice, but unfortunately, a common one. I'm sure the second `#` is for symmetry, but it serves no real purpose. Even quotes can fail if the value contains its own quote(s), though this particular usage is guaranteed not to have quotes. The only absolutely safe way that works in all scenarios is to use delayed expansion instead.

Comment: @ivy_lynx The implementation in `Strawberry Perl` is error-prone. It fails when the current directory contains a `&` like in `C:\Projects & etc\Strawberry`. Quotes should be used always with directories to be safe, `set "drive=%~dp0"`

Comment: Is there any documentation for the meaning of special characters like # in batch files?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Microsoft never documents anything properly so, to my knowledge, the only real source is https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html

Comment: That's a great site but I don't know where to look for the pound sign.

Comment: Might even not be there, idk. I might have even checked it out back then and made this question because I didn't find anything. I can't remember and I unfortunately can't help with a proper reference as I don't know of any other.